# How to use IF statement for JOINS - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a inner join depending a value. for example:

```
SET @Value = FALSE;
IF(@Value)
THEN
 SELECT * FROM TABLEA
 INNER JOIN TABLEB PWO ON PWO.product_id = TP.id
ELSE
 SELECT * FROM TABLEA
END
```

I Don't want to use IF Statement.
Is there any way?

I don't want to use `IF` statement because my codes are over 200 lines and using an IF statement make a huge duplicate codes

Comment: The columns/structures of the two resut sets are different.  Your current approach seems like a good one.  What is the issue with it?

Comment: because my codes are over 200 lines and using an `IF` statement make a huge duplicate codes.

Comment: This query will return a lot of copies if more than one record in `tableB` matches and  `@Value != FALSE`. Does you need in this?

Comment: Moreover, the final recordset structures differs. Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR` operator on `@Value` conditions.

```
select * from tableA
where (id in (select product_id from tableB) and @Value = TRUE)
    or @Value = FALSE
```

Comment: This is not a solution. The original query will return a lot of copies if more than one record in `tableB` matches.

Comment: @Akina, OP just needed a hint, how to prevent using IF